# PHP Postgresql query results in malformed array literal with large array

Tags: php, postgresql, php-pgsql

I'm trying to pass an array in a sql query using PHP.

Here's my php script :

```
$php_array = json_decode($_POST['id'], true);
$arr = '{'.implode(', ',$php_array).'}';  
$sql = "SELECT tableB.id, tableB.names, from tableA inner join tableB
on tableA.id like '%' || tableB.id || '%' where tableB.id = ANY($1)
GROUP BY tableB.id, tableB.names
ORDER BY tableB.names DESC;";
$result = pg_prepare($db, "query", $sql);
$query = pg_execute($db, "query", array($arr));
```

This query usually works. However, with my real dataset which includes around 29'000 ids (i.e. my array will have a lenght of 29'000) I end up with the following error message :

```
Warning: pg_execute(): Query failed: ERROR: malformed array literal: "{12345, 56789, 13579, ...}"
DETAIL: Unexpected "," character. CONTEXT: unnamed portal parameter $1 = '...'
```

I've check, and the array seems ok.

Do you have an idea what might be causing this issue ?

Comment: My first guess is that there's a limit to `ANY`, or, even though you say "seems ok", that there is a very tiny bug, like maybe a null. I'd take `$php_array` and chop it in half. Send the first, and if that passes, send the second. If either fails, debug. If both pass, experiment with maximum size limits such as 28,000, then 25,000 and so on to see if you can find what breaks. It might be number of items, or it might be bytes.

Comment: Just print the sql string to check what it's output, like `echo($sql);`

Comment: PostgreSQL can work with json, why don't you use one of the json function in PostgreSQL to handle your json input?